# Kohana 3 - Redirect to other localhost project

Tags: php, redirect, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

```
$this->request->redirect('localhost/project2/');
```

From a controller in project1, I have this code, but it's always redirecting me to ***localhost/project1/index.php/localhost/project2***. How can I properly redirect to ***localhost/project2/*** ?

I tried using `header()` to redirect but its not working in Kohana. Im using Kohana 3.2 in PHP 5.5.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use http before link to specify it is a complete URL:

```
$this->request->redirect('http://localhost/project2/');
```

And you shouldn't use the localhost as a static text in your code because your server will changed, you should use on of the ways to return your server root like $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] or if you use a MVC framework you can use its function that return base URL.